# can we use height attribute for entry widget if root is frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to increase a height of few columns so I am using a height attribute but it is giving an error that it does not have any attribute called height.

I tried on python 3.1.7

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import*
window=Tk()
window.geometry("800x800")
window.title("Qualifications")
cf1=Frame(window,width=20,height=20)
cf1.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=3)
for i in range(1,10):
   for j in range(2,3):
      txt1=Entry(cf1,width=30,height=20)
      txt1.grid(row=i,column=j)
window.mainloop
```

> tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"

Answer (score 1):

The [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget has no direct option for setting height. But you can increase padding by `ipady` parameter when calling `grid` function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import*
window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x800")
window.title("Qualifications")
cf1 = Frame(window, width=20, height=20)
cf1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(2, 3):
        txt1 = Entry(cf1, width=30)
        txt1.grid(row=i, column=j, ipady=20)
window.mainloop()
```

Another option is to use [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) widget which has the `height` parameter:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import*
window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x800")
window.title("Qualifications")
cf1 = Frame(window, width=20, height=20)
cf1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(2, 3):
        txt1 = Text(cf1, width=20, height=2)
        txt1.grid(row=i, column=j)
window.mainloop()
```